# how to make a secure login page with hash crypt ,compare?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

How can I make a secure login page with password encryption to any hash then compare it with the hash password from database. , ( md5 or .. )

I mean , the users is writing his password , the page code will convert his password into a hash the save it to database and next time compare again his crypted password with the hash in the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has already done this for you, with the [SqlMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx). If this does not fit your needs, you could write your own custom implementation of [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx), but always try to use the components that the framework offers instead of rolling your own solution to a problem that has been solved many times before.